# ElasticSearch: Attempting to get spelling suggestion on proper names

Tags: elasticsearch, tokenize, analyzer, search-suggestion

Before I begin, let me just say that I'm no ElasticSearch expert, but I am currently tasked with tweaking some analyzers to get spelling suggestions working better in a couple of different situations.  I've seen examples of people who are doing spelling suggestions on proper names, so I know it must be possible, but I've been at this for a couple days now, and I must be missing something, because ElasticSearch doesn't seem to recognize the name I'm looking for.  Can you please help me figure this out?  Thanks in advance!

Here's the analyzer I'm using for index as well as search:

```
"full_text": {
    "filter": [
        "lowercase",
        "asciifolding",
    ],
    "type": "custom",
    "tokenizer": "keyword"
},
```

This should demonstrate that the field is tokenizing into one long keyword, which I want.

```
{
    "query": {
       "match": {
           "_all": "combine 5"
       }
    },
    "script_fields": {
        "terms" : {
            "script": "doc[field].values",
            "params": {
                "field": "my_field"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

...and it outputs something like this, which shows how the field is being tokenized.  Looks good:

```
"took": 7,
"timed_out": false,
"_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
},
"hits": {
    "total": 75,
    "max_score": 0.58574116,
    "hits": [
        {
            "_index": "my_index",
            "_type": "thing",
            "_id": "1",
            "_score": 0.58574116,
            "fields": {
                "terms": [
                    [
                        "combine 5"
                    ]
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

... but when I do a suggest query, it doesn't suggest the field, even though it's just off by a space.

```
{
  "query": {
     "match": {
         "_all": "combine 5"
     }
  },
  "suggest": {
    "suggest-0": {
      "term": {
        "field": "_all",
        "size": 5
      },
      "text": "combine5"
    }
  }
}
```

Which returns a bunch of documents and this suggestion:

```
"suggest": {
    "suggest-0": [
        {
            "text": "combine5",
            "offset": 0,
            "length": 8,
            "options": [
                {
                    "text": "combined",
                    "score": 0.875,
                    "freq": 15
                },
                {
                    "text": "combine",
                    "score": 0.85714287,
                    "freq": 17
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Note that if I change the spelling suggestion to work just on the field that contains the text, it does suggest it, but not when I'm using _all.  Is there a way to get the words in a specific field to be suggested when suggesting against _all?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this qualifies as exactly the answer I was looking for, but I ended up solving this by adding a field on the document containing the keyword value that I was looking for "combine5", so now it is registered as a word and if I suggest on that field, or _all, the word is suggested.  It's also found in queries against _all.